# Overflow oculta el contenido pero no añade ellipsis

Tags: html, css, text

Me encuentro desarrollando un apartado de la página que consta de tarjetas que contienen una imagen de cabecera y un pequeño resumen sobre el contenido debajo.
Quiero que el resumen de abajo tenga un ancho y largo especifico y que si se produce `overflow` me añada una `ellipsis`. 
Hasta ahora he conseguido que se oculte el texto que sobresale pero no me añade la `ellipsis`.

Adjunto código

CODIGO HTML

```
<div class="articulo">
                <div class="imagen"></div>
                <div class="resumen">
                    <h3>Título</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti alias ducimus eius ad
                        facere,
                        quidem optio odio, illo odit, nobis magnam quo natus? Corporis obcaecati natus quas expedita
                        eius
                        minus!
                    </p>
                </div>
                <a href="#">Ver más</a>
            </div>
```

CODIGO CSS:

```
    .articulo{
        background-color: white;
        margin: 4%;
    }

    .resumen{
    width: 380px;
    margin: -6% 2% 2% 2%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}


    .articulo:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .imagen{
        background: url(../img/prueba.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 80%;
        height: 200px;
    }
```

Comment: Editada mi respuesta para contemplar que se corte el texto solamente de cada línea del párrafo que exceda el límite, no de todo el párrafo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que lo que se busca es que el texto, al superar a su contenedor, sea el que se corte y muestre una elipsis, es al párrafo (que es el contenedor del texto) al que debemos darle las propiedades:

**CSS**

```
.resumen p {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

**Ejemplo**

```css
.articulo {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 4%;
}
        
.resumen{
  width: 380px;
  margin: -6% 2% 2% 2%;
}

.resumen p {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: pre;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
        
.articulo:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
        
.imagen{
  background: url(../img/prueba.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 80%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="articulo">
  <div class="imagen"></div>
  <div class="resumen">
    <h3>Título</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti alias ducimus eius ad
        facere,
        quidem optio odio, illo odit, nobis magnam quo natus? Corporis obcaecati natus quas expedita
        eius
        minus!
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti alias ducimus eius ad
        facere,
        quidem optio odio, illo odit, nobis magnam quo natus? Corporis obcaecati natus quas expedita
        eius
        minus!
      </p>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Ver más</a>
</div>
```

**Editado**

Con `white-space: nowrap` lo que provocas es que los saltos de líneas que tienes dentro del `<p>` no sean interpretados, mostrando todo el contenido en una sola línea. Usando `white-space: pre;` conseguirías lo que creo que pretendes alcanzar.

Comment: Efectivamente de esa manera aparece la ellipsis. No obstante el contenido del párrafo solo muestra una línea de texto. No rellena el heigth que le asigno al párrafo.